# Parallel run with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have several (few hundreds) of files to run test on (each test takes few minutes).

Running sequentially is not acceptable and neither all together. So I am looking for something like a producer-consumer.

I tried pipeline jobs and parallel command the following way:

```groovy
def files = findFiles glob: 'test_files/*'
def branches = [:]

files.each{
    def test_command = "./test ${it}" 
    branches["${it}"] = { sh "${test_command} ${it}"}
}

stage name:'run', concurrency:2
parallel branches
```

Problem:

All the tasks are launch at the same time (OOM and all the fun)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't have the same introspection as the Jenkins parallel step, but since it seems not to support a fixed pool you can use `xargs` to achieve the same result:

```
def files = findFiles glob: 'test_files/*'
def branches = [:]

// there's probably a more efficient way to generate the list of commands
files.each{
    sh "echo './test ${it}' >> tests.txt" 
}

sh 'cat tests.txt | xargs -L 1 -I {} -P 2 bash -c "{}"'
```

The `-P` argument is the one that specifies a fixed number of 2 (or N) processes should always be running. Other tools like GNU Parallel offer even more tuning on how many processes should be used.

You can also try to use the `lock` step from the [Lockable Resources plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin), the `node` step targeting a fixed number of executors. However this seems too much overhead to me unless your single tests are already taking tens of second each.